# JPA retrieve certain fields from named query

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have the following entity (Person) with a relationship with @onetoone with (Direction)

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="PERSON)
    class Person { 
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DIRECTIONID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Direction direction  ;
    }
```

And the entity Direction

```
@Entity
@Table(name=DIRECTION)
class Direction{
...
@Id
@Column(name = "DIRECTIONID")
private Integer directionId;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
private String description;

@Column(name = "KEY")
private String key;

}
```

I have the the following named query

```
select p from Person p
```

However I get from the result the fields directionId,description and key . I need to retrieve only the description from the direction entity without doing a named query like

```
Select p.description from Person p
```

Is there any way to accomplish that ?

Comment: Another way is to use Criteria API

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this:

```
select p, p.direction.description from Person p
```